# Cargar Select Dependiente por Defecto sin alterar a los demas

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, select

Tengo un select dependiente, que carga los valores a traves de una funcion.
Funciona todo ok, pero ahora debo cargar uno por defecto y mostrar sus opciones sin alterar el funcionamiento de los demas select.
Tengo lo siguiente:

```
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">TIPO VENTA</label>
            <?php
            $consulta = "SELECT id, nombre FROM tipo_venta WHERE estado = 'S'";
            $resultado = $conexion->query($consulta);
              if ($resultado->num_rows > 0){
              echo "<select name='tipo' id='tipo' class='form-control select2' style='width: 100%;'>";
              echo "<option value='' selected='selected'>SELECCIONE TIPO VENTA</option>";
              while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "<option value='".$row['id']."'>".utf8_encode(strtoupper($row['nombre']))."</option>";
                }
              echo '</select>';
            }else{
              echo "AUN NO INGRESA TIPO DE VENTAS";
            }
            ?>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.col -->
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">PRODUCTO</label>
            <select name="prod" class="form-control select2" id="prod" onChange='activa_boton(this,this.form.boton)'>
              <option value='' selected='selected' disabled="disabled">SELECCIONE PRODUCTO</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Donde el primer select es el padre y el segundo es el hijo (por llamarlo de alguna forma).
La funcion que hace el cambio de productos, segun el elegido en el primer select es:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#tipo").change(function () {
    $("#tipo option:selected").each(function () {
    id = $(this).val();
        $.post("ajax/tipo_prod.php", { id: id }, function(data){
            $("#prod").html(data);
        });
    });
})
});
```

Todo funciona bien, pero ahora necesito, que al cargar la pagina principal, se muestre el tipo de venta 1 tambien me cargue en el segundo select, los productos asociados al tipo de venta1, esto sin alterar el correcto funcionamiento de los otros selects y tambien sin alterar mucho la funcion que he descrito.
Alguna idea u orientacion de como hacer esto?
Saludos y gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes forzar que se dispare el evento change con la función trigger() al principio:

```
$('#tipo').trigger('change');
```

Pon lo anterior dentro del ready.

Comment: gracias por responder, pero hace lo mismo de antes, necesito que se cargue el valor 1 (lo cual puedo hacer) y se cargue el dependiente que corresponde al valor 1 (lo cual es lo que nececito hacer).

Comment: Vale, asigna primero el valor y luego dispara el evento: $('#tipo').val('1').trigger('change');

Comment: lo hice y efectivamente, me carga en el primer select el valor 1, pero en el segundo select, no me muestra los datos asociados al valor 1 del primer select y esto igual debe ser de manera automatica.

Comment: Pensándolo bien, si por defecto necesitas la opción 1, yo lo haría directamente con php. 
Luego ya el código jQuery para cuando haya cambios.